# Reading jar output from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jar

I am running some function form a jar(located under `WEB-INF/lib`) and I want to read the `output`(to the `console`) from my `servlet`. here is the code:

```
MsgTranToXML = new MsgTranToXML(); //this is a function inside the jar that prints output
```

Is this possible? thank's.

Comment: Does a servlet always have a console?

Comment: I didn't understant the quastion....

Comment: Servlets are only 'alive' for the duration of a request processing. Does the servlet launch the jar, or is the external process already running?

Comment: It is the servlet that runs this jar, so while the request ends the servlet could not read from 'println'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your function prints its output via `System.out.println`.

`System.out.println` means "call the `println()` method on the static field `out` of the class `System`.
This `out` field is of type `PrintStream`, and can be reassigned by calling `System.setOut()` and passing it a new `PrintStream` of your choice, which you can then use to read the output generated by your function (you may want to take a look at the `PipedOutputStream`/`PipedInputStream` classes to achieve that).

Be aware though, that you will also trap the output of every other method that uses `System.out.println` (including any library you may also use in your application) !